# How to query waypoints as direction pairs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a waypoint's latitude, longitude, and a timestamp. I need to aggregate this information in pairs, that would represent the movement from point A to B, based on sequential timestamps, grouped by day (it should no generate a pair between the last point of day 1 and first of day 2).

Could someone please shed me a light on how I should approach on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked at LEAD (and LAG) windowing functions?

Comment: @Hogan, thanks for the input. I have, but the LAG function only accepts one column as its input. Idk how I would be able to get all columns on this scenario. I don't know if it is okay to use one LAG for each column.

Comment: Just use it multiple times `SELECT COLA, LEAD(COLA), COLB, LEAD(COLB), .. etc`